# How to position 3 buttons in StackLayout equal width

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Anyone know how to position 3 buttons in `StackLayout` with equal width?  I have it working with `Grid` with

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Grid.Row="0" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Button1}"  HeightRequest="{Binding Width}">
```

I would like to find a way to show 3 buttons on same line  with same width equally without a `Grid`
For example all 3 buttons of equal length fitting across horizontally in `StackLayout`

[   Button 1   ]  [   Button 222   ]  [   Button 333333   ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Button Text="Button 1" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.0000,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,Factor=.3333,Constant=0}"/>
    <Button Text="Button 222" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.3333,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,Factor=.3333,Constant=0}"/>
    <Button Text="Button 333333" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.6666,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,Factor=.3333,Constant=0}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

StackLayout:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button x:Name="button1" Text="Button 1"/>
    <Button Text="Button 222" WidthRequest="{Binding Path=Width, Source={x:Reference button1}}"/>
    <Button Text="Button 333333" WidthRequest="{Binding Path=Width, Source={x:Reference button1}}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: that' doesn't seem fill entire horizontal space

Comment: Awesomely suit my need. Simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Still using Grid, just specify width of columns in percent (col spacing set for fun):

```
    <Grid 
     ColumnDefinitions="33.33*, 33.33*, 33.33*"
     ColumnSpacing="8" 
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Button Text="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <Button Text="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <Button Text="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>          
     </Grid>
```

[image]

Updated: use one-line ColumnDefinitions property in Xamarin.Forms 4.8

Comment: This looks like a better solution than what I did with a Grid. Thank you for your idea. I'll wait to see if someone has a good idea with StackLayout. If not I will mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: Although, it should be pointed out that there's no need for `33.33*`s. You could simply write: `ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *"`.

Comment: No need ColumnDefinitions. Because default is 33.33* (if there is 3 columns)

Answer (score 4):

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="2" Padding="2">
            <Button Text="Move Up" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" TextColor="Black" />
            <Button Text="Move Down" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" TextColor="Black" />
            <Button Text="Move Right" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" TextColor="Black" />
            <Button Text="Move Left" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" TextColor="Black" />
</StackLayout>
```

Seems like an old thread, but for anyone who might want to implement with `StackLayout`, this will accurately place the buttons with equal spacing in horizontal orientation.

Comment: That would only work if the children of the `StackLayout` have content with the same width.  If the children all contain different content (eg.  `Grid`s each with different content instead of `Button`s), their spacing won't be equal.

Comment: Yes ! That’s right. But the question is about spacing buttons of equal width.

Answer (score 0):

Flexlayout provides an easy solution for this, by setting its Direction property as "Row" and JustifyContent property as "SpaceEvenly".
Please find the code below:

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" AlignItems="Center" 
JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" HeightRequest="50">
    <Button Text="Button 1" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    <Button Text="Button 2" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
    <Button Text="Button 3" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine"/>
</FlexLayout>
```

[Solution using Flexlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8AS0.png)